# SQL Server stored procedure in Python pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I need to run a stored procedure in Python using pyodbc. The stored procedure (SP1) takes a list in apostrophe  (' ') like the following in SQL Server:

```
EXEC SP1 'A,B,C'
```

I wrote this code in Python to retrieve its data:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=10.2.10.30;Database=BETA ; UID=123;PWD=123;')

A=pd.read_sql_query("EXEC SP1 'A,B,C'" ,conn)
```

However, I get an error saying:

> columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

I am not sure if writing a apostrophe inside the other one  (" ' ' ") makes the issue or it is because of other problem. Could you please help me how to solve it?

Comment: Where is that code being called? Can you add the rest of the code needed to replicate this issue (specific connection details excluded)?

Comment: Does your stored procedure start with `SET NOCOUNT ON;` ?

Comment: @GordThompson  No, it is running properly as " EXEC SP1 'A,B,C' " in SSMS. I have to note that the SP was written by our database support company and I am not aware of their scripts. I can only call it and get the data by passing a list into it.

Comment: @C.Nivs I run it in SSMS. it is all I use and runs properly in SSMS.

Comment: you have `EXEC` twice, have you removed the redundancy?                `A=pd.read_sql_query("EXEC EXEC SP1 'A,B,C'" ,conn)`

Comment: Lack of `SET NOCOUNT ON;` is a common cause of "works in SSMS but not in Python" issues.

Comment: @TaylorFrancis Sorry it was a type in my question. There is only one "EXEC" in my code.

Comment: @GordThompson Hi Gord. Thanks for your help. Could you please explain it more to me? Do you mean "SET NOCOUNT ON;" should be added to the stored procedure ? How does it work in SP?